# Spark mapping a Dataframe to another Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse a column of a dataframe into two different columns (with the aim to add these columns to the dataframe afterwards). I tried two approaches. Both lead to problems. Can anyone show me how to achieve this with one of the methods or hint me to a different approach?

### Map `Dataset<Row>` to `Dataset<Tuple2<String, String>>`

```
Dataset<Tuple2<String, String>> dfParsed =  df.map(new MapFunction<Row, Tuple2<String, String>>
            () {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, String> call(Row value) throws Exception {
            // Parse the column
            String opsCode = value.getAs("OPSCODE");
            String[] splitted = opsCode.split("[\\.|\\-]");

            return new Tuple2<>(splitted[1], splitted[2]);

        }
    }, Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(), Encoders.STRING()));
```

This works. But in `dfParsed` both columns are named `value` and I can not select them to add them to the original dataframe.

### Map `Dataset<Row>` to `Dataset<Row>`

```
Dataset<Row> dfParsed =  df.map(new MapFunction<Row, Row>() {

        @Override
        public Row> call(Row value) throws Exception {

            // Parse the column
            String opsCode =   value.getAs("OPSCODE");
            String[] splitted = opsCode.split("[\\.|\\-]");

            //return RowFactory.create(splitted[1], splitted[2]);
       }
    }, ???);
```

This approach does not work because I don't know which `Encoder` to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `toDF(columnNames)` after your first attempt to rename the columns.

```
output.toDF("col1", "col2", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works even easier with an `selectExpr` statement, because it already appends the new columns to the dataframe. (And hereby adding them with a join statement or similar can be avoided)

```
Dataset<Row> dfParsed = df.selectExpr("*",
    "split(OPSCODE, '[\\.|\\-]')[1] as OPSCODE_CAT",
    "split(OPSCODE, '[\\.|\\-]')[2] as OPSCODE_PROC ");
```

The SQL `split` command is used to split the column "OPSCODE" with an regular expression. The second part of the splitted string is stored in a new column "OPSCODE_CAT", the third in "OPSCODE_PROC".